# "Old-Fashioned" O-level Maths Book

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, soft-question, education, book-recommendation

I'm looking for recommendations for an "old-fashioned" style of maths textbook for O-level/GCSE, i.e., one which is concise (not full of pictures) with plenty of exercises. Ideally something which is available in PDF format online. I don't necessarily mean an old book, more a book written in a style which is typical of the early 20th century or earlier. (For instance, [Gwynne's Latin](http://gwynneteaching.com/gwynnes-latin/) is a modern book for learning Latin which I would consider to fall under this category.)

I am quite fond of [this one](https://books.google.com.mt/books/about/New_Comprehensive_Mathematics_for_O_Leve.html?id=wX2dxeDahAwC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) which I own a physical copy of, but am struggling to find anywhere online in PDF format.

Also I would appreciate if it is just one book rather than many volumes. A lot of maths textbooks made for school come in many volumes with titles like "School Maths 1A, 1B, 2A, 2B", etc.

---

To clarify, by "O-level/GCSE", I mean a book with a table of contents which should at least tackle all of the following:

[image]

Comment: What sort of maths? Algebra? Trigonometry/Precalculus? Calculus?

Comment: @Countable O-level, so basically up to middle school. Basic things like percentages and so on, up to quadratic equations.

Comment: I mean at that level I think probably you should try Khan Academy or look at some videos online otherwise.

Comment: Can i recommend seperate books for seperate sections? They are quite old, and suitable for the level, but I am sorry, they are 2 separate ones by two authors........Rest assured they are of the highest quality among the old ones

Comment: @Aatmaj Of course, go ahead.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend something like [this](http://www.mathscentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/hobsonajjustthemaths20021296smcetp.pdf). It's not specifically for O Level's or GCSE's but I've found it to be an excellent textbook.

Alternatively, if you are just looking for the facts and how to use the facts (so without any, or with very few proofs) then I can recommend the CGP GCSE Maths study guides. They are extremely cheap and extremely good, complete with plenty of examples and exercises.

You can also buy a CGP GCSE Maths questions book that is meant as a companion to the main study guide; it contains hundreds of questions, and is once more also very cheap. The links are below:

https://www.cgpbooks.co.uk/secondary-books/gcse/maths/mxhr47-new-2021-gcse-maths-edexcel-revision-guide

https://www.cgpbooks.co.uk/secondary-books/gcse/maths/mxhq42-gcse-maths-edexcel-exam-practice-workbook-h

They also have an option of an all-in one maths GCSE book, complete with practice as well:

https://www.cgpbooks.co.uk/secondary-books/gcse/maths/mxhs44-new-2021-gcse-maths-edexcel-complete-revisi

Personally, I would go for the book that is linked directly above, as well as the practice exam workbook as a bonus; thay are what I used (mainly the all in one book) for my GCSE Maths and they served me very well.

Comment: This is definitely not an O level/GCSE book.

Comment: @PeterPhipps I realize but it contains many things that a GCSE includes.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent recommendation.

Comment: @LukeCollins it's my pleasure, I'm glad I've helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

For part 1 and 2--[Higher algebra by hall and knight](https://www.pdfdrive.com/higher-algebra-hall-knight-e60359347.html)
For part 3-[Coordinate geometry by sl looney](https://www.pdfdrive.com/s-l-loney-s-coordinate-geometry-with-solutions-of-examples-math-valley-e187498613.html)

Well these were books which take from beginner level to advanced level of maths,(nothing off topic but deeper in the topics you mentioned). They being pretty concise (plenty of questions included). are ideal for someone who has the knack of solving problems. (I am sure you do :~)

I really do not know what level of difficulty you want, but the theory is really ideal for your description, even if some of the questions (especially from higher algebra) might be a little too difficult to crack for school students, in case you want it for teaching.  The questions are really fun to solve, but not intended for someone who is scared of difficult problems being thrown at him.

For part 4, here is the school textbook [statistics](http://ncertbooks.prashanthellina.com/class_10.Mathematics.Mathematics/Chap-14.pdf)
and [probability](http://ncertbooks.prashanthellina.com/class_10.Mathematics.Mathematics/Chap15%20.pdf), which is old fashioned in all but the language......

Since the curriculum varies slightly from place to place, it is indeed difficult to get every subtopic in one place........but youtube is always there.

Being widely popular books, I am sure that you will be able to find the solutions of all the books mentioned online too

You might want to check these out
disclaimer- I don't own the  copyrights :~)

1. [New Syllabus Mathematics for O-Level 1](https://1lib.in/book/2668821/ec1873)
2. [New Syllabus Mathematics for O-Level 2](https://1lib.in/book/2676314/11ca15)

Comment: also, if anyone wants books meant especially for problem solving, I could provide some oldies